# Initialize multiple drop down lists in one function vb.net

Tags: vb.net, drop-down-menu

I have function that initializes Drop Down List

```
    Dim myCommand As OracleCommand = Nothing
    myCommand = _myConnection.CreateCommand()
    myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    myCommand.CommandText =
        "text"

    ddlStandort.DataSource = myCommand.ExecuteReader()
    ddlStandort.DataTextField = "value"
    ddlStandort.DataValueField = "value"
    ddlStandort.DataBind()
```

Now I have four more Drop Down Lists that I want to initialize. How can i do this without repeating my code four times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming each DDL needs to be populated with the exact same data, the easiest way is to convert that code into a method that accepts a DropDownList as a parameter, then call that method for each of the dropdownlists.

```
Private Sub PopulateDDL(byref theDDL as DropDownList)
    Dim myCommand As OracleCommand = Nothing
    myCommand = _myConnection.CreateCommand()
    myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    myCommand.CommandText = "text"

    theDDL.DataSource = myCommand.ExecuteReader()
    theDDL.DataTextField = "value"
    theDDL.DataValueField = "value"
    theDDL.DataBind()
End Sub
```

Make calls like

```
PopulateDDL(ddlStandort)
PopulateDDL(ddlTwo)
PopulateDDL(ddlThree)
...
```